# Get the view name of a CAD imports in Revit

Tags: linq, revit-api

I am making a list of CAD imports in a Revit project to include import ID, import name, view Id, and view name. I have 3 out of 4. I cannot get the view name from the view Id.

the filtered element collector gets import instances and returns import Id, import name, and view Id

```
public ObservableCollection<ImportWrapper> GetCadImport()
    {
        var colImportInstances = new FilteredElementCollector(Doc)
            .OfClass(typeof(ImportInstance))
            .Select(x => new ImportWrapper(x, null));

        return new ObservableCollection<ImportWrapper>(colImportInstances);
    }

        return new ObservableCollection<ImportWrapper>(colImportInstances);
```

the import wrapper passed into the observable collection is

```
public ImportWrapper(Element importInstance, View view)
    {
        ImportName = importInstance.Category.Name;
        ElementId = importInstance.Id;
        Doc = importInstance.Document;
        ViewId = importInstance?.OwnerViewId;
        var viewelement = Doc.GetElement(importInstance.OwnerViewId);
        var view = viewelement as View;
        ViewName = view?.Name;

    }
```

how can I get the view name from the ownerViewId here? I tried empty string and null but the view name is not reassigned

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `OwnerViewId` to open the corresponding `View` object and retrieve its [`Name` property](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/e372092e-ff47-71c2-1272-50ab08e5a41d.htm). Does that give you what you need?

Comment: yes it does thanks! I removed ViewName = "" and added  the last 3 lines in the ImportWrapper. before I was trying to get the view from the wrapper - the view should come from the document

Comment: No need for the cast to `View`. The name property belongs to the base class `Element`.